# Rails has_many does not update on save if parent has not been changed

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following relationship between models:

```
class Gift 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :constituents, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :constituents
end


class Constituent
    has_and_belongs_to_many :gifts
    has_many :addresses, :autosave => true
end

class Address 
    belongs_to :constituent
end
```

In my controller `@gift.save` updates the appropriate `address` record ONLY if there is a change detected in its `constituent` record.

But if there is a change in the `address` record but none in its `constituent` record, the `address` record is NOT updated.

In my controller, I am simply running the `save!` method:

```
def create
    @gift = Gift.new
    @gift.assign_attributes gift_params
    p @gift.constituents[0].addresses[0].changed? #Prints true
    @gift.save!
end

def gift_params
    params.require(:gift).permit(:amount, :constituents_attributes => [:id, :organization_name, :title_id, :first_name, :last_name, :addresses_attributes => [ :id, :address_type, :address1, :address2, :city, :country_id, :state_id, :pin_code, :constituent_id ]])
end
```

An example of the params is:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "gift"=>
    {"constituents_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"5", "title_id"=>"", "first_name"=>"Mridula", "last_name"=>"Prabhu", 
        "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"16", "constituent_id"=>"5", "address_type"=>"home", "address1"=>"Line1", "address2"=>"Line2", "city"=>"Pune", "country_id"=>"38", "state_id"=>"53", "pin_code"=>"M2M 2M2"
        }
    }, 
    "amount"=>"20" 
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you please show permitted params inside the controller.

Comment: @VishalTajPM I have updated the post.